Is the function field of a projective variety a finitely generated algebra?
I am currently reading Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, and I got stuck at the function fields of projective varieties:
The question that came up to me in this context and on which I will expand upon below is:
Is $S(Y)_{((0))}$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra? Here $S(Y)_{((0))}$ is the homogeneous coordinate ring of $Y$, localized at the zero-ideal $(0)$ and then we take the subset of degree $0$ elements.
Another follow-up question that just came up to me in this context:
Is there are general relation between the dimension of $K(Y)$ and the dimension of $Y$ for a projective variety?
By Theorem 3.4c) in Hartshorne we know that for an projective variety $Y$ with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$, $K(Y)\cong S(Y)_{((0))}$, where $K(Y)$ is the function field of $Y$. As $(0)$ is a minimal prime ideal $S(Y)_{(0)}$ has Krull dimension zero and, in particular, its subset of degree $0$ elements $S(Y)_{((0))}$ has. However, $K(Y)$ does not always have dimension zero, where the dimension is the transcendence degree. This is because, for the homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$, the Krull dimension does not equal the transcendence degree of its quotient field, as is the case for affine varieties (Prop 1.7 and Theorem 1.8A).
But that these two types of dimensions do not coincide means that Theorem 1.8A. is not applicable to $S(Y)_{((0))}$, but why? In my opinion, it should be an integral domain, as $S(Y)$, localization maintains this property, and the subset of degree zero elements also does not change anything. Thus, $S(Y)_{((0))}$ must not be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Obviously, $S(Y)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Thus, either the localization must fail to maintain this property or taking the subset of degree $0$ elements must fail:
The localization is definitely still a module, and I think that it should also still be an algebra, as its ring structure should still be compatible with the module structure. Also, taking the subset of degree $0$ elements should be closed under addition and multiplication; thus, it also forms an algebra.
Therefore, I'd expect that the property of being finitely generated is not maintained. Can anyone argue why this is the case? Are there any conditions on the ideal that we are localizing at such that the localization is a finitely generated algebra?
I would highly appreciate any help on this!
Edit: Inspired by Anuradha Narasimhan's answer, I think I got a proof for $\dim K(Y)=\dim Y$: Let $Y_i$ be the affine charts of $Y$, then $K(Y)=K(Y_i)$ for each $i$. By Theorem 3.2, $\dim K(Y_i)=\dim Y_i$ and by exercise 1.10b), $\dim Y=\sum\dim Y_i$. Chosing the chart that realizes this supremum, we get
\begin{equation*}
\dim K(Y)=\dim K(Y_i)=\dim Y_i=\dim Y.
\end{equation*}

In the simple case of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, the function field is $k(t)$.  Do you want to see a proof that $k(t)$ is not a finitely generated $k$-algebra?  (The essential idea is just that a finite number of generators only allow for poles at a finite number of points, which handles the case of infinite $k$.  For finite $k$, you need to consider poles at elements of the algebraic completion instead, or maybe just poles at some large enough finite extension of $k$ would be enough.)

True, thank you for your hint on this. Indeed, as $k$-algebra for an infininite $k$, $k(t)$ is generated by $t$ and all terms $1/f$ for all irreducible polynomials $f$ in $k(t)$.

The function field of $Y$ is a subfield of the field of fractions of a finitely generated $k$-algebra.  Here, you are making a mistake that
$K(Y) \cong S(Y)_{((0))}$; $K(Y)$ is the "subfield" (of $S(Y)_{((0))}$) generated by ratios of homogenous elements of $S(Y)$ of the same degree. And it turns out that the dimension of $Y$ is the same as the dimension (or transcendence degree) of $K(Y)$.
Also, $S(Y)_{((0))}$ being the field of fractions of $S(Y)$ (which is a f.g. $k$-algebra), naturally has Krull dimension zero (any field has Krull dimension zero); but the dimension of $K(Y)$ (as defined by its transcendence degree) is equal to the Krull dimension of the subring (domain) of which it is the field of fractions. I hope I have answered your question.
Edit: I looked up Hartshorne, and found that I misunderstood his notation for $S(Y)_{((0))}$ that he defines as the degree zero elements of the graded ring defined by it (I mistook his notation to mean the domain $S(Y)$ localized at the zero prime ideal) -- but this is precisely the same as the subfield of the field of fractions of $S(Y)$ generated by ratios of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, coming from $S(Y)$. So the idea is essentially the same, and by Hartshorne's notation, indeed $K(Y) \cong S(Y)_{((0))}$.
In the context of the comment by @Daniel Schepler, the function field $k(t)$ of $\mathbf{P}_k^1$ can be understood to be the subfield of the field $k(t, t')$ generated by ratios of homogeneous polynomials of same degree from the ring $k[t, t']$; an element of $k(t)$ can be obtained by dehomogenizing any such ratio at the variable $t'$. Conversely, the numerator and denominator of any rational function in $k(t)$ may be homogenized with respect to the variable $t'$ to obtain a ratio as above. This clarifies the abstract ideas in this concrete context.

Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I am not quite understanding it. You claim that $K(Y)\cong S(Y){((0))}$ is not correct, but that $K(Y)$ is only isomorphic to a subfield of $S(Y){((0))}$, right? But $K(Y)\cong S(Y)_{((0))}$ is precisely the statement of Theorem 3.4c) in Hartshorne. Or what am I misunderstanding here?

Please give me some time to refer to Hartshorne and get back to you. Perhaps you are misunderstanding the notation in Hartshorne ?  I will write back tomorrow (it is close to 2 am IST here).

In fact $K(Y)\cong S(Y)_{((0))}$ as the latter is the subfield of degree zero elements in the localization of $S(Y)$ at the homogeneous prime ideal $(0)$. See page 18, the paragraph immediately before theorem I.3.4, as referenced in this recent question.

@HyperPro see above - I realized you probably didn't get a notification of this.
